# design-pattern to store a "absolute xor incremental" value

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

In a application data entry, I allow the user to insert a numeric value that can represent two different things:

1. an absolute value, say 5, meaning that a property P should be assigned the value 5
2. a relative value, say +5, meaning that the property P should be incremented by 5

My question is: which data-structure use to store this inforation?
I lay down some alternatives.
My idea is going with the 3rd idea, but I wonder is the pattern is "correct".

1) 
Here the absolute xor the increment is assigned, the other left null. Not very satisfactory.

```
class DoubleFieldBased {
    Integer absolute;
    Integer increment; 
}
```

2)
Here the "magnitude" of the value is saved into "value", while the boolean "increment" tells wheter the value is absolute or relative. Even less satisfactory.

```
class FieldAndBoolean {
    Integer value;
    boolean increment;
}
```

3)Here I move the focus to the method applyValue, that uses polymorphism and do the right thing based on the implicit information of what class "am I". Satisfactory but a bit complex, and I suspect the pattern isn't perfect.

```
public static abstract class AbstractValue {
    int myvalue;
    public AbstractValue (int myvalue) {this.myvalue = myvalue;}
    public abstract int applyValue (int value);
}

public static class Absolute extends AbstractValue {
    public Absolute (int myvalue) {super(myvalue);}
    public int applyValue (int value) {
        return value;
    }
}

public static class Incremental extends AbstractValue {
    public Incremental (int myvalue) {super(myvalue);}
    public int applyValue(int value) {
        return myvalue + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does you Absolute class in the 2nd snippet means to set myvalue = value and then return myvalue?

Comment: sorry mistake, it has to return myvalue. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say use an Integer or other numeric type) and an enum, something like this:

```
enum Type{
ABSOLUTE, INCREMENT, PERCENTAGE /* etc */
}

public class Value{
    int /* or float */ numericValue;
    Type type;
}
```

You could even use the enum as strategy:

```
enum Type{
  ABSOLUTE{
      public int apply(int newValue, int oldValue){return newValue;}
  }, INCREMENT{
      public int apply(int newValue, int oldValue){return oldValue + newValue;}
  } /* etc */
  ;
  public abstract int apply(int newValue, int oldValue);
}
```

Comment: Ok, the "Type" soution is very elegant, far more compact than mine and more readable too. However it is conceptually equivalent to the AbstractValue approach. Thinking of something radically different, i would say that I need to store two things: 1) a value 2) an "operation". (Notice that the operation is something that will be done on another class, the one that contains the value to set or increment). Maybe something reflection based?

Comment: @AgostinoX, reflection could cost performance. Think twice, before use it. In this and your 3rd solution we both instead of one value operate two things: value & operation. When value -- are our classic value and operation is none, +, -, *, /, %, etc. This is normal pattern, but I`m still not sure that here we don`t have sone hiddne problems.

Comment: @gaRex Reflection is cheap these days, that's not the problem. All major frameworks use it, all the time. The problem is that you are losing compile-time safety whenever you use reflection.